# Rotate incomplete box so it is vertical

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a dataset of x-ray images that i am trying to clean by rotating the images so the arm is vertical and cropping the image of any excess space. Here are some examples from the dataset:

[image: scans]

I am currently working out the best way to work out the angle of the x-ray and rotate the image based on that.

My curent approach is to detect the line of the side of the rectangle that the scan is in using the hough transform, and rotate the image based on that.

I tried to run the hough transform on the output of a canny edge detector but this doesnt work so well for images where the edge of the rectangle is blurred like in the first image.

I cant use cv's box detection as sometimes the rectangle around the scan has an edge off screen.

So i currently use adaptive thresholding to find the edge of the box and then median filter it and try to find the longest line in this, but sometimes the wrong line is the longest and the image gets rotated completley wrong.

Adaptive thresholding is used due to the fact that soem scans have different brightnesses.

The current implementation i have is:

```
def get_lines(img):
  #threshold
  thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 4.75)
  median = cv2.medianBlur(thresh, 3)
  # detect lines
  lines = cv2.HoughLines(median, 1, np.pi/180, 175)
  return sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x[0][0], reverse=True)

def rotate(image, angle):
  (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
  (cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)

  M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), angle, 1.0)
  cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
  sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

  nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
  nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

  M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
  M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

  return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))

def fix_rotation(input):
  lines = get_lines(input)
  rho, theta = lines[0][0]
  return rotate_bound(input, theta*180/np.pi)
```

and produces the following results:

[image: intermediate results of current implementation]

When it goes wrong:

[image]

I was wondering if there are any better techniques to usein order to improve the performance of this and what the best way to go about cropping the images after they have been rotated would be?

Comment: Share the link to download a few original images.

Comment: @karlphillip Link to some images is [here](https://postimg.cc/gallery/2ck1asvgc/)

Comment: The edges of the box surely are artificial and not meant to be used in this task... I imagine the method is supposed to use the actual arm and line it up with the axis?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use the blob of the arm itself and fit an ellipse around it. Then, extract its major axis. I quickly tested the idea in **Matlab** – not OpenCV. Here's what I did, you should be able to use OpenCV's equivalent functions to achieve similar outputs.

First, compute the threshold value of your input via Otsu. Then add some bias to the threshold value to find a better segmentation and use this value to threshold the image.

In pseudo-code:

```
//the bias value
threshBias = 0.4;

//get the binary threshold via otsu: 
thresholdLevel = graythresh( grayInput, “otsu” );

//add bias to the original value
thresholdLevel = thresholdLevel - threshSensitivity * thresholdLevel;

//get the fixed binary image: 
thresholdLevel = imbinarize( grayInput, thresholdLevel );
```

After small blob filtering, this is the output:

[image]

Now, get the contours/blobs and *fit an ellipse* for each contour. Check out the OpenCV example here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.9/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html

You end up with two ellipses:

[image]

We are looking for the biggest ellipse, the one with the biggest area and the biggest major and minor axis. I used the width and height of each ellipse to filter the results. The target ellipse is then colored in green. Finally, I get the major axis of the target ellipse, here colored in yellow:

[image]

Now, to implement these ideas in **OpenCV** you have these options:

- Use `fitEllipse` to find the ellipses. The return value of this
  function is a `RotatedRect` object. The data stored here are the
  vertices of the ellipse.
- Instead of fitting an ellipse you could try using `minAreaRect`, which
  finds a rotated rectangle of the minimum area enclosing a blob.

Answer (score 2):

You can use image moments to calculate the rotation angle.
Using opencv [moments](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#moments) function, calculate the second order central moments to construct a covariance matrix and then obtain the orientation as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Central_moments) in the **Image moment** wiki page. 
Obtain the normalized central moments `nu20`, `nu11` and `nu02` from opencv `moments`. Then the orientation is calculated as

`0.5 * arctan(2 * nu11/(nu20 - nu02))`

Please refer the given link for details.

You can use the raw image itself or the preprocessed one for the calculation of orientation. See which one gives you better accuracy and use it.

As for the bounding-box, once you rotate the image, assuming you used the preprocessed one, get all the non-zero pixel coordinates of the rotated image and calculate their upright bounding-box using opencv [boundingRect](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#boundingrect).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you elaborate more on how to use moments to find the rotation of the image?

Comment: @user6817585 Please follow the like I have given above. There's an example given under 'Central moments' section that clearly explains how to do this.